# Find a plane parallel to a given vector and containing two given points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to find a plane parallel to vector (1, 1 ,-2) and passing by the two points
- A (0, -1, 5) and B (2, 0, -2)

So what I did is found vector AB which is (2, 1, -7)

I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I know I need to find the normal of the equation to the plan, so I need two vectors. Can I just use the vector (1, 1 , -2) and (2, 1 , -7)? then put in a point to find d in the form ax + by+ cz + d

Answer (score 1):

Vector
$$
(1,1,-2)\times(2,1,-7)=(-5,3,-1)
$$
is perpendicular to both vectors and thus normal to the plane.

Comment: Do you mean (1, 1, -2) X (2, 1, -7) will give a vector perpendicular to both which is the normal of a plane. So if i use that as my normal, my plane will be parallel to (1, 1, -2)?

Comment: Yes, and sorry for the wrong sign: I'll correct at once.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel to $v$ and passing through $a$ and $b$: $$x=a+\lambda v +\mu(b-a).$$